# Difficulty with a tricky matrix exponential step

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

I am having great difficulty checking a step involving operations with 2x2 matrix exponentials.

The expression I would like to simplify is

$$\lim _{x\to \infty} e^{-iHt-Vt}$$

where, for some $\epsilon, x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we define

$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \epsilon \\ 
\epsilon & 0
\end{bmatrix} \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } 
V=\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 \\ 
0 & y
\end{bmatrix}$$

the undecipherable line says "we easily find that this expression equals

$$\lim _{x\to \infty} e^{-iHt-Vt}=e^{-yt}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

...". After more than an hour of work, I am not convinced it is so easy. Any assistance or ideas would be of great value.

The necessary information is all on this post, but [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qANNX.jpg) is an image of the source if it is helpful to anyone. That image is a standalone section. I was able to prove every step until this one (used BCH formula for A6).

Edit: Here is a previous approach which seems to have gotten to the wrong conclusion (maybe limit composition is illegal in this situation?). The last steps uses the same property as in Omnomnomnom's answer for exponentiating projectors.

$$\lim _{x\to \infty} e^{-iHt-Vt}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} (e^{-itH/x-t P_- -ytP_+ /x})^x$$

$$\to \lim_{x\to \infty} (e^{-t P_-})^x$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} (I+(e^{-tx}-1)P_-)$$
$$\to P_+ \neq e^{-yt} P_+$$

where $P_-, P_+$ are diag(1,0) and diag(0,1) respectively.

Comment: Are you sure that it is *only* a limit over $x$? Perhaps they are also taking $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: It would be equivalent to show that 
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty} e^{yt}e^{-iHt-Vt}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
With that said, we have
$$
\exp(yt)\exp(-iHt-Vt) = \exp(Iyt)\exp(-iHt-Vt) = \exp(Iyt - iHt - Vt) =\\
\exp\left[t\pmatrix{y - x & -i\epsilon\\ -i\epsilon & 0} \right].
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom They don't take $\epsilon \to 0$ (I included an image of the source). I am playing with your suggestion now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be equivalent to show that 
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty} e^{yt}e^{-iHt-Vt}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
With that said, we have
$$
\exp(yt)\exp(-iHt-Vt) = \exp(Iyt)\exp(-iHt-Vt) = \exp(Iyt - iHt - Vt) =\\
\exp\left[t\pmatrix{y - x & -i\epsilon\\ -i\epsilon & 0} \right].
$$
In other words: it suffices to show that for $k,z \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
\lim_{z \to \infty} \exp \pmatrix{-z&-ik\\-ik&0} = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}.
$$
Take $Q(z,k) = \pmatrix{-1&-\frac{ik}{z}\\ - \frac{ik}z & 0}$. We find that $Q$ has eigenvalues
$$
\lambda_\pm = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4 \epsilon^2/z^2}}{2}.
$$
Note that for large $z$, $\lambda_+ \approx 0$ and $\lambda_- \approx -1$. We can write
$$
Q(z,k) = \lambda_+ P_+ + \lambda_-P_-,
$$
where $P_\pm$ denote the projections onto the eigenspaces corresponding to $\lambda_{\pm}$. 
By the continuity of eigenvalues/eigenvectors, we have 
$$
\lambda_-(z) \to -1,\quad z\lambda_+(z) \to 0, \quad P_-(z) = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad P_+(z) = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}.
$$

Note that $P_{\pm}$ commute. So, we have
$$
\lim_{z \to \infty} \exp \pmatrix{-z&-ik\\-ik&0}
= \lim_{z \to \infty} \exp(z\lambda_+ P_+ + -z\lambda_-P_-)
= \\ \lim_{z \to \infty} \exp(z\lambda_+ P_+)  \exp(-z\lambda_-P_-) = \\
\lim_{z \to \infty} \exp(z\lambda_+ P_+) \cdot \lim_{z \to \infty} \exp(z\lambda_-P_-)
$$
Now, it suffices to note that for any projection $P$, we have $\exp(tP) = I + (\exp(t) - 1)P$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to \infty} \exp(z\lambda_+ P_+) &= 
\lim_{z \to \infty} I + (\exp(z \lambda_+) - 1)P_+
\\ &= \lim_{z \to \infty} I + (\exp(z \lambda_+) - 1)\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1} = I\\
\lim_{z \to \infty} \exp(z\lambda_- P_-) &= 
\lim_{z \to \infty} I + (\exp(z \lambda_-) - 1)P_-\\
&= \lim_{z \to \infty} I + (\exp(z \lambda_-) - 1)\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0} = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}.
\end{align}
$$
The conclusion follows.

---

An abbreviation of the above derivation: note that

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to -\infty}\exp\left[t\pmatrix{y - x & -i\epsilon\\ -i\epsilon & 0} \right] &= 
\lim_{x \to \infty}\exp\left[x t\pmatrix{\frac{y - x}x & \frac{-i\epsilon}x\\ \frac{-i\epsilon}x & 0} \right]
\\ & = 
\lim_{x \to \infty}\exp\left[x t\lim_{x \to \infty}\pmatrix{\frac{y - x}x & \frac{-i\epsilon}x\\ \frac{-i\epsilon}x & 0} \right]
\\ & = 
\lim_{x \to \infty}\exp\left[x t\lim_{x \to \infty}\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&0} \right]
= \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1},
\end{align} 
which was what we wanted.

Comment: I suspect that my "limit in the limit" trick in the abbreviated version is a bit problematic.  For instance, we obviously can't say that 
$$
1 = \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 = \lim_{x \to \infty}(x \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty}(1/x)) = \lim_{x \to \infty}(1 \cdot 0) = 0.
$$

Comment: How can we justify using the already-limited eigendecomposition in the equation after "So, we have"? Seems the same as limit composition law with matrices (as in the abbreviation), is there such a theorem? I tried using the same assumption and got a different answer: $\lim e^{-iHt-Vt}=\lim (e^{-itH/x-t P_- -ytP_+ /x})^x \to \lim (e^{-t P_-})^x=\lim 1+(e^{-tx}-1)P_-\to P_+$. Sorry that is a mess, I have edited the same math into the end of the question for clarity.

Comment: @d I suspect that we can get away with it because the limit of the first term is invertible

Comment: Well, I just did everything by hand on mathematica to double check and it seems to work! Thanks for all the help. Still wish I knew why the original thing I had didn't work (or what assumption it was missing to work) but this is great. +1

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced by the end of the Omno's calculation.

We assume that $t>0$. Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}-z&-ik\\-ik&0\end{pmatrix},w=\sqrt{z^2-4k^2},u=-\dfrac{1}{2}(z+w),v=-\dfrac{1}{2}(z-w)$.

Note that, when $z\rightarrow +\infty$, $u\sim -z,w\sim z$ and $v\rightarrow 0$ (the indeterminacy is here; in particular, a (simple) calculation is necessary).

$\exp(A)=B$ where

[image]

$b_{1,1}\sim \exp(u)\rightarrow 0,b_{1,2}\sim \dfrac{-ik}{z}\rightarrow 0,b_{2,2}\sim \dfrac{-u}{w}\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: How did you calculate $B$, is it from a spectral decomposition into $A = \lambda_1 P_1 + \lambda_2 P_2$? And then using the commutation of projectors to split the exponential & simplify?

Comment: No, Maple does the job and I use the parameters $u,v$ which are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I attempted the same on mathematica & got the same results. It is valuable to see consistency here. I agree that there is a step in Omnomnomnom's answer which I am uncertain about, nonetheless it was helpful to me in understanding the problem more deeply, as was your answer as well.